# Hibernate Criteria query using AND,OR operator

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

In my application I have two entity class `User`,`Activity`.

Activity class is :

```
 public class Activity{
 private Set<User> users;
 private Set<User> activityManagers;
 }
```

and class User is :

```
 public class User{
 private String userName;
 }
```

Now I want to retrieve, using Hibernate Criteria all `Activities` having a `User` with `username` set to a certain value, in property `users` or `managers` or both.
 I have tried this:

```
Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Activity.class, "act");
criteria.createAlias("act.activityManagers", "manager");
criteria.createAlias("act.users", "user");
criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(Restrictions.eq("manager.username", userName)).add(Restrictions.eq("user.username", userName)));
criteria.setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
```

It is not working properly .Where I have done wrong I don't know. can anyone help me? Thanks

UPDATE-1
  Suppose I have 5 `Activity`s

```
First Activity:users[aaa,bbb,cccc],managers[ddddd].
Second Activity:users[userName,dddd],managers[userName,xxx,gggg].   
Third Activity:users[userName,vvvvv,bbbb],managers[sss,cccc,tttt].
Fourth Activity:users[aaa,ffff,jjjj],managers[userName,uuuu,iiiii].
Fifth Activity:users[dddd,ffff],managers[jjjjj,iiii].
```

Result must be Second,Third,Fourth Activity. But I am getting only Thired Activity.

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: It is not giving expected answer @Thihara .

Comment: @Diganta what is the input, what is the expected output, and what is the actual output? Help us helping you.

Comment: What do you expect and what is the output you are getting instead?

Comment: In my application I have 2 `Activity`s having `managers` equal to `userName` string, and one `users` equal to `userName` string. I should obtain 3 rows, but I am getting one row ,`Activity` containing `managers`'s username equal to userName. @Thihara

Comment: @ JB Nizet:I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unit testing your code ?

I see you're using `activityManagers` in your criteria compared to `managers` in your Activity class.

`criteria.createAlias("act.activityManagers", "manager");`

maybe that could be the reason why you don't have the 2 `managers` on result?

Comment: Have you tried replacing 'activityManagers' in your criteria with 'managers' like I answered you ?

Comment: Thank u @DrSeb for reply: sorry I was typed wrong, property name is `activityManagers` not `managers`, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is doing exactly what you're asking him to do, but your probably not getting the query you want.

Add this to your hibernate.cfg file:

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
```

Then trigger the query from your application and copy the generated query from the console, and try it directly in your sql intarface, you will find out whats being generated and what you really wanted.